# Can int be used for primary keys in PostgreSQL clusters \ replication?

Tags: postgresql

I'm planning a database that might in future be used in a clustered \ replicated manner. However, the question is if I can actually use integer for primary keys  in this case or I must consider using string UUIDs for primary keys to avoid potential replication issues?

I've looked into the [High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html) documentation but there is no mention of the actual keys as a consideration. Does it mean that any potential conflicts are resolved somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't use `int` for replication.  `int` isn't "unique" enough.

Comment: An `uuid` is not a string

Comment: If you are referring to Postgres' built-in replication: it works perfectly fine with any PK you define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked into the High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication documentation but there is no mention of the actual keys as a consideration. Does it mean that any potential conflicts are resolved somehow?

By definition, a **Primary Key** is unique.  Therefore, you shouldn't run into any conflict.  However, if you're planning to use multi-master replication, you could run into insert-insert conflicts, where two nodes choose to insert with the same PK value.  If this happens, it's not due to data type selection (i.e., int v. uuid v. something-else), and your replication engine should be selected based on whether it has the mechanism to resolve the conflicts for you.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)